# How to find DOS Header and PE Header with an entry point in Radare2?

Tags: disassembly, radare2, pe

I am currently doing byte extraction from PE files using Radare2. I know how to find the byte sequence for DOS Header and PE Header when there is no entry point and the start is defaulted to 0x0. But some of them have an entry point at `0x4#####`.

I can retrieve the `vaddr` (virtual address), `paddr` (physical address), and `haddr`  (e_entry\AddressOfEntryPoint in the binary header) of a certain file with an entry point.

How do I use that to find the byte sequence for the DOS Header and PE Header?

[image: entry point address]

Answer (score 1):

You can load the file as raw, using `-n` or `-nn` option and then you will have those structures available at `0x0`.

```
r2 -n ./open-wsl.exe
```

[image]

It also contains some function to operate and print on those structures in a nicer form. Check the `pf?` group for more info.